# Error messages thrown inconsistently, unknown reason. Want all error messages to disappear

Tags: java, eclipse

For a school project, I made a program that reads input from a file and constructs a bar chart to represent some data found in the input. Input is read line by line, and the bar chart is updated for each line. For every line that's been read, ("line %d\n", lineNumber) is printed to the console. All these functions have been implemented, and they work. However, the program throws exceptions to the console, and I want them to go away. Here is an excerpt from the console:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" line 4
line 5
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Color parameter outside of expected range: Red
at java.awt.Color.testColorValueRange(Color.java:310)
at java.awt.Color.<init>(Color.java:395)
at java.awt.Color.<init>(Color.java:369)
at ui.staafdiagram.StaafDiagramPanel.berekenKleur(StaafDiagramPanel.java:62)
at ui.staafdiagram.StaafDiagramPanel.tekenStaaf(StaafDiagramPanel.java:106)
at ui.staafdiagram.StaafDiagramPanel.paintComponent(StaafDiagramPanel.java:162)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1045)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:878)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:585)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:878)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5219)
at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1236)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1031)
at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:78)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:115)
at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1967)
line    at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3877)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:807)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:784)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:784)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:757)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:706)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(RepaintManager.java:62)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1651)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)6
    //more errors....   PS Note the '6' at the end of this block of code. Error message thrown from within out.printf("line %d\n", lineNumber)?
```

For some reason I can't understand, error messages are thrown differently for each time the program is run with the same input, with the same code. For example, I get this when I run again:

```
    line 1
    line 2
    line 3
    line 4
    line 5
    line Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Color parameter outside of expected range: Red
    6
    line    at java.awt.Color.testColorValueRange(Color.java:310)
    //more errors...
```

Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
private void processInput() {

    Scanner input;
    Scanner lineScanner = null; // initialization

    String line;
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int lineNumber = 0;
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        lineNumber++;
        out.printf("line %d\n", lineNumber);

        line = input.nextLine();
        lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
        if (line.length() < MIN_OK_LINE_LENGTH)
            continue;
        incrementBar(gameResult(lineScanner));
        barChart.showChanges();
    }
    input.close();
    lineScanner.close();
}
```

Will post more console errors and program code if requested. My program uses methods from the University java libraries, any error message not in  english has its roots in methods I'm not familiar with the code of.

Comment: If a program throws exceptions, ***something*** is wrong.  Debug the program to understand why the exceptions are thrown.

Comment: Well what does ui.staafdiagram.StaafDiagramPanel.berekenKleur(StaafDiagramPanel.java:62) look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I do agree with the other answers: **You should find the bug, fix it and send the bugfix to the library maintainer/author**. You might even get extra credit from your professor, you never know. In this case, somewhere in `ui.staafdiagram.StaafDiagramPanel` a wrong color value is assigned (not in range 0-255).

You never know what parts of your program might break if you just ignore thrown unchecked exceptions, really *anything* could happen!

However, maybe you have a demo coming up and can't find the bug in time. Exceptions are usually printed out to stderr, so you could just ignore the output from stderr completely:

```
System.setErr(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        //nothing
    }
}));
throw new RuntimeException("test"); //this should not be printed, ever.
```

Keep in mind that this will swallow all Exceptions and your program might just fail without warning and without printing a cause.

Answer (score 3):

The error message indicates that the java.awt.Color constructor was called with a value for the Red component that is out of range.  Looking at the javadoc for Color, we see that red is an 8-bit value, i.e., between 0-255.  Look in your code for something that represents a color, and discover why it sometimes gives a color that has (at least) red out of this range.  If something is reading data, or randomly generating the color value, then that explains why it does not happen at a consistent time.

Be aware that the value may be int or float -- again, looking at the different constructors for Color will tell you what is expected.  And we don't know that the colors for green and blue are valid, just that red is not.

Comment: Yes, I reinterpreted "want all errors to go away" as "want to find and fix all errors".  I don't think it realistic to just "want errors to go away", hopefully OP wasn't hoping for magic.